# ESXi 5 licencing

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I have dedicated server with one physical CPU (socket) and 64GB RAM. I have ESXi 5 installed trial for 60 days (I didn't apply any licence and it is coming to an end). I have 5 virtual machines using about 50GB of RAM.

Now I need to apply some licence key. When I registered at vmware.com and downloaded ESXi 5 i got some free licence key and when I tried to enter it, it said "vRAM per CPU entitlement 32 GB". What exactly does this means? I read something about it and as I understood it means that all my VM can use only 32GB of RAM, all of them? Is that correct? If so, that really sucks.

And if it is true, what licence I need to buy so that all my virtual machines can continue to work. I asked also at vmware.com but they still don't answer me.

Thanks in advance. I would really appreciate your help.

OK. Sorry for bad question. It just cost me a ban, so I can't ask questions any more. Although this is a place to post questions and answers (can you imagine)? 
Anyway, I figured this out. Licencing model has changed. It is based on number of physical processors.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Licensing questions are off-topic. Call a vendor. That said, a single license of vSphere 5 Standard currently allows for a single socket of any amount of cores + 32GB vRAM. Enterprise and Enterprise Plus have higher vRAM entitlements.

Comment: You have three (non-deleted) questions, one of which is closed and downvoted. The other two are okay so I cannot understand why you are "banned" - what do you mean by "banned?" "Not accepting questions from this account" or similar?

Comment: Also it's impossible to update every single question as time passes.

Comment: I am banned so that I can't ask quiestiones anymore. Because of just one question. Can you imagine that?

Comment: It's never for just one question. If you delete other bad questions that you've asked, they still count against you. If you have a problem, post it on [meta] where a moderator can see it.

Answer (score 2):

It means you can allocate 32GB of ram to your VMs on that host before exceeding the licence limits.

And you might think that it sucks, but it's free, if you spend more money with them you can have a heck of a lot more.

Comment: So this means that I will lose some of my VMs if I apply this licence of 32GB vRAM since my VMs use about 50GB of RAM?

Comment: I'm no expert on the free version to be honest but with the paid version you can go over the limit by varying degrees with only a warning about being in violation of the licence but there is a level where it will stop you adding more. I don't think it'll stop your current VMs but it may stop them restarting.